# how to change header color with midnight.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to change the color of the menu letters.
However, some problems arise.

The problem is that when I enter this jquery code the menu gets all centered
[https://imgur.com/4196CgN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnkXJ.jpg)

The goal of this jquery is to change the color of the header when it arrives in another section by assigning it a class.
If the header is between two sections, above it takes the color of the previous section, and below it takes the color of the next section.

```js
/*!
 * Midnight.js 1.1.1
 * jQuery plugin to switch between multiple fixed header designs on the fly, so it looks in line with the content below it.
 * http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Aerolab <info@aerolab.co>
 *
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/LICENSE.txt
 */
!function(t){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],t):t(jQuery)}(function(t){var e=0,s=Array.prototype.slice;t.cleanData=function(e){return function(s){var i,n,o;for(o=0;null!=(n=s[o]);o++)try{i=t._data(n,"events"),i&&i.remove&&t(n).triggerHandler("remove")}catch(r){}e(s)}}(t.cleanData),t.widget=function(e,s,i){var n,o,r,a,h={},d=e.split(".")[0];return e=e.split(".")[1],n=d+"-"+e,i||(i=s,s=t.Widget),t.expr[":"][n.toLowerCase()]=function(e){return!!t.data(e,n)},t[d]=t[d]||{},o=t[d][e],r=t[d][e]=function(t,e){return this._createWidget?void(arguments.length&&this._createWidget(t,e)):new r(t,e)},t.extend(r,o,{version:i.version,_proto:t.extend({},i),_childConstructors:[]}),a=new s,a.options=t.widget.extend({},a.options),t.each(i,function(e,i){return t.isFunction(i)?void(h[e]=function(){var t=function(){return s.prototype[e].apply(this,arguments)},n=function(t){return s.prototype[e].apply(this,t)};return function(){var e,s=this._super,o=this._superApply;return this._super=t,this._superApply=n,e=i.apply(this,arguments),this._super=s,this._superApply=o,e}}()):void(h[e]=i)}),r.prototype=t.widget.extend(a,{widgetEventPrefix:o?a.widgetEventPrefix||e:e},h,{constructor:r,namespace:d,widgetName:e,widgetFullName:n}),o?(t.each(o._childConstructors,function(e,s){var i=s.prototype;t.widget(i.namespace+"."+i.widgetName,r,s._proto)}),delete o._childConstructors):s._childConstructors.push(r),t.widget.bridge(e,r),r},t.widget.extend=function(e){for(var i,n,o=s.call(arguments,1),r=0,a=o.length;a>r;r++)for(i in o[r])n=o[r][i],o[r].hasOwnProperty(i)&&void 0!==n&&(e[i]=t.isPlainObject(n)?t.isPlainObject(e[i])?t.widget.extend({},e[i],n):t.widget.extend({},n):n);return e},t.widget.bridge=function(e,i){var n=i.prototype.widgetFullName||e;t.fn[e]=function(o){var r="string"==typeof o,a=s.call(arguments,1),h=this;return o=!r&&a.length?t.widget.extend.apply(null,[o].concat(a)):o,r?this.each(function(){var s,i=t.data(this,n);return"instance"===o?(h=i,!1):i?t.isFunction(i[o])&&"_"!==o.charAt(0)?(s=i[o].apply(i,a),s!==i&&void 0!==s?(h=s&&s.jquery?h.pushStack(s.get()):s,!1):void 0):t.error("no such method '"+o+"' for "+e+" widget instance"):t.error("cannot call methods on "+e+" prior to initialization; attempted to call method '"+o+"'")}):this.each(function(){var e=t.data(this,n);e?(e.option(o||{}),e._init&&e._init()):t.data(this,n,new i(o,this))}),h}},t.Widget=function(){},t.Widget._childConstructors=[],t.Widget.prototype={widgetName:"widget",widgetEventPrefix:"",defaultElement:"<div>",options:{disabled:!1,create:null},_createWidget:function(s,i){i=t(i||this.defaultElement||this)[0],this.element=t(i),this.uuid=e++,this.eventNamespace="."+this.widgetName+this.uuid,this.bindings=t(),this.hoverable=t(),this.focusable=t(),i!==this&&(t.data(i,this.widgetFullName,this),this._on(!0,this.element,{remove:function(t){t.target===i&&this.destroy()}}),this.document=t(i.style?i.ownerDocument:i.document||i),this.window=t(this.document[0].defaultView||this.document[0].parentWindow)),this.options=t.widget.extend({},this.options,this._getCreateOptions(),s),this._create(),this._trigger("create",null,this._getCreateEventData()),this._init()},_getCreateOptions:t.noop,_getCreateEventData:t.noop,_create:t.noop,_init:t.noop,destroy:function(){this._destroy(),this.element.unbind(this.eventNamespace).removeData(this.widgetFullName).removeData(t.camelCase(this.widgetFullName)),this.widget().unbind(this.eventNamespace).removeAttr("aria-disabled").removeClass(this.widgetFullName+"-disabled ui-state-disabled"),this.bindings.unbind(this.eventNamespace),this.hoverable.removeClass("ui-state-hover"),this.focusable.removeClass("ui-state-focus")},_destroy:t.noop,widget:function(){return this.element},option:function(e,s){var i,n,o,r=e;if(0===arguments.length)return t.widget.extend({},this.options);if("string"==typeof e)if(r={},i=e.split("."),e=i.shift(),i.length){for(n=r[e]=t.widget.extend({},this.options[e]),o=0;i.length-1>o;o++)n[i[o]]=n[i[o]]||{},n=n[i[o]];if(e=i.pop(),1===arguments.length)return void 0===n[e]?null:n[e];n[e]=s}else{if(1===arguments.length)return void 0===this.options[e]?null:this.options[e];r[e]=s}return this._setOptions(r),this},_setOptions:function(t){var e;for(e in t)this._setOption(e,t[e]);return this},_setOption:function(t,e){return this.options[t]=e,"disabled"===t&&(this.widget().toggleClass(this.widgetFullName+"-disabled",!!e),e&&(this.hoverable.removeClass("ui-state-hover"),this.focusable.removeClass("ui-state-focus"))),this},enable:function(){return this._setOptions({disabled:!1})},disable:function(){return this._setOptions({disabled:!0})},_on:function(e,s,i){var n,o=this;"boolean"!=typeof e&&(i=s,s=e,e=!1),i?(s=n=t(s),this.bindings=this.bindings.add(s)):(i=s,s=this.element,n=this.widget()),t.each(i,function(i,r){function a(){return e||o.options.disabled!==!0&&!t(this).hasClass("ui-state-disabled")?("string"==typeof r?o[r]:r).apply(o,arguments):void 0}"string"!=typeof r&&(a.guid=r.guid=r.guid||a.guid||t.guid++);var h=i.match(/^([\w:-]*)\s*(.*)$/),d=h[1]+o.eventNamespace,l=h[2];l?n.delegate(l,d,a):s.bind(d,a)})},_off:function(e,s){s=(s||"").split(" ").join(this.eventNamespace+" ")+this.eventNamespace,e.unbind(s).undelegate(s),this.bindings=t(this.bindings.not(e).get()),this.focusable=t(this.focusable.not(e).get()),this.hoverable=t(this.hoverable.not(e).get())},_delay:function(t,e){function s(){return("string"==typeof t?i[t]:t).apply(i,arguments)}var i=this;return setTimeout(s,e||0)},_hoverable:function(e){this.hoverable=this.hoverable.add(e),this._on(e,{mouseenter:function(e){t(e.currentTarget).addClass("ui-state-hover")},mouseleave:function(e){t(e.currentTarget).removeClass("ui-state-hover")}})},_focusable:function(e){this.focusable=this.focusable.add(e),this._on(e,{focusin:function(e){t(e.currentTarget).addClass("ui-state-focus")},focusout:function(e){t(e.currentTarget).removeClass("ui-state-focus")}})},_trigger:function(e,s,i){var n,o,r=this.options[e];if(i=i||{},s=t.Event(s),s.type=(e===this.widgetEventPrefix?e:this.widgetEventPrefix+e).toLowerCase(),s.target=this.element[0],o=s.originalEvent)for(n in o)n in s||(s[n]=o[n]);return this.element.trigger(s,i),!(t.isFunction(r)&&r.apply(this.element[0],[s].concat(i))===!1||s.isDefaultPrevented())}},t.each({show:"fadeIn",hide:"fadeOut"},function(e,s){t.Widget.prototype["_"+e]=function(i,n,o){"string"==typeof n&&(n={effect:n});var r,a=n?n===!0||"number"==typeof n?s:n.effect||s:e;n=n||{},"number"==typeof n&&(n={duration:n}),r=!t.isEmptyObject(n),n.complete=o,n.delay&&i.delay(n.delay),r&&t.effects&&t.effects.effect[a]?i[e](n):a!==e&&i[a]?i[a](n.duration,n.easing,o):i.queue(function(s){t(this)[e](),o&&o.call(i[0]),s()})}}),t.widget}),function(t){"use strict";t.widget("aerolab.midnight",{options:{headerClass:"midnightHeader",innerClass:"midnightInner",defaultClass:"default",classPrefix:"",sectionSelector:"midnight"},_headers:{},_headerInfo:{top:0,height:0},_$sections:[],_sections:[],_scrollTop:0,_documentHeight:0,_transformMode:!1,refresh:function(){this._headerInfo={top:0,height:this.element.outerHeight()},this._$sections=t("[data-"+this.options.sectionSelector+"]:not(:hidden)"),this._sections=[],this._setupHeaders(),this.recalculate()},_create:function(){var e=this;this._scrollTop=window.pageYOffset||document.documentElement.scrollTop,this._documentHeight=t(document).height(),this._headers={},this._transformMode=this._getSupportedTransform(),this.refresh(),setInterval(function(){e._recalculateSections()},1e3),e.recalculate(),t(window).resize(function(){e.recalculate()}),this._updateHeadersLoop()},recalculate:function(){this._recalculateSections(),this._updateHeaderHeight(),this._recalculateHeaders(),this._updateHeaders()},_getSupportedTransform:function(){for(var t=["transform","WebkitTransform","MozTransform","OTransform","msTransform"],e=0;e<t.length;e++)if(void 0!==document.createElement("div").style[t[e]])return t[e];return!1},_getContainerHeight:function(){var e=this.element.find("> ."+this.options.headerClass),s=0,i=0,n=this;return e.length?e.each(function(){var e=t(this),o=e.find("> ."+n.options.innerClass);o.length?(o.css("bottom","auto").css("overflow","auto"),i=o.outerHeight(),o.css("bottom","0")):(e.css("bottom","auto"),i=e.outerHeight(),e.css("bottom","0")),s=i>s?i:s}):s=i=this.element.outerHeight(),s},_setupHeaders:function(){var e=this;this._headers[this.options.defaultClass]={};for(var s=0;s<this._$sections.length;s++){var i=t(this._$sections[s]),n=i.data(this.options.sectionSelector);"string"==typeof n&&(n=n.trim(),""!==n&&(e._headers[n]={}))}({top:this.element.css("padding-top"),right:this.element.css("padding-right"),bottom:this.element.css("padding-bottom"),left:this.element.css("padding-left")});this.element.css({position:"fixed",top:0,left:0,right:0,overflow:"hidden"}),this._updateHeaderHeight();var o=this.element.find("> ."+this.options.headerClass);o.length?o.filter("."+this.options.defaultClass).length||o.filter("."+this.options.headerClass+":first").clone(!0,!0).attr("class",this.options.headerClass+" "+this.options.defaultClass):this.element.wrapInner('<div class="'+this.options.headerClass+" "+this.options.defaultClass+'"></div>');var o=this.element.find("> ."+this.options.headerClass),r=o.filter("."+this.options.defaultClass).clone(!0,!0);for(var n in this._headers)if(this._headers.hasOwnProperty(n)&&"undefined"==typeof this._headers[n].element){var a=o.filter("."+n);a.length?this._headers[n].element=a:this._headers[n].element=r.clone(!0,!0).removeClass(this.options.defaultClass).addClass(n).appendTo(this.element);var h={position:"absolute",overflow:"hidden",top:0,left:0,right:0,bottom:0};this._headers[n].element.css(h),this._transformMode!==!1&&this._headers[n].element.css(this._transformMode,"translateZ(0)"),this._headers[n].element.find("> ."+this.options.innerClass).length||this._headers[n].element.wrapInner('<div class="'+this.options.innerClass+'"></div>'),this._headers[n].inner=this._headers[n].element.find("> ."+this.options.innerClass),this._headers[n].inner.css(h),this._transformMode!==!1&&this._headers[n].inner.css(this._transformMode,"translateZ(0)"),this._headers[n].from="",this._headers[n].progress=0}o.each(function(){var s=t(this),i=!1;for(var n in e._headers)e._headers.hasOwnProperty(n)&&s.hasClass(n)&&(i=!0);s.find("> ."+e.options.innerClass).length||s.wrapInner('<div class="'+e.options.innerClass+'"></div>'),i?s.show():s.hide()})},_recalculateHeaders:function(){this._scrollTop=window.pageYOffset||document.body.scrollTop||document.documentElement.scrollTop,this._scrollTop=Math.max(this._scrollTop,0),this._scrollTop=Math.min(this._scrollTop,this._documentHeight);var t=this._headerInfo.height,e=this._scrollTop+this._headerInfo.top,s=e+t;if("function"==typeof window.getComputedStyle){var i=window.getComputedStyle(this.element[0],null),n=0,o=0;if(this._transformMode!==!1&&"string"==typeof i.transform){var r=i.transform.match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)/g);null!==r&&r.length>=6&&!isNaN(parseFloat(r[5]))&&(o=parseFloat(r[5]))}i.top.indexOf("px")>=0&&!isNaN(parseFloat(i.top))&&(n=parseFloat(i.top)),e+=n+o,s+=n+o}for(var a in this._headers)this._headers.hasOwnProperty(a)&&(this._headers[a].from="",this._headers[a].progress=0);for(var h=0;h<this._sections.length;h++)s>=this._sections[h].start&&e<=this._sections[h].end&&(this._headers[this._sections[h].className].visible=!0,e>=this._sections[h].start&&s<=this._sections[h].end?(this._headers[this._sections[h].className].from="top",this._headers[this._sections[h].className].progress+=1):s>this._sections[h].end&&e<this._sections[h].end?(this._headers[this._sections[h].className].from="top",this._headers[this._sections[h].className].progress=1-(s-this._sections[h].end)/t):s>this._sections[h].start&&e<this._sections[h].start&&("top"===this._headers[this._sections[h].className].from?this._headers[this._sections[h].className].progress+=(s-this._sections[h].start)/t:(this._headers[this._sections[h].className].from="bottom",this._headers[this._sections[h].className].progress=(s-this._sections[h].start)/t)))},_updateHeaders:function(){if("undefined"!=typeof this._headers[this.options.defaultClass]){var t=0,e="";for(var s in this._headers)this._headers.hasOwnProperty(s)&&""!==!this._headers[s].from&&(t+=this._headers[s].progress,e=s);t<1&&(""===this._headers[this.options.defaultClass].from?(this._headers[this.options.defaultClass].from="top"===this._headers[e].from?"bottom":"top",this._headers[this.options.defaultClass].progress=1-t):this._headers[this.options.defaultClass].progress+=1-t);for(var i in this._headers)if(this._headers.hasOwnProperty(i)&&""!==!this._headers[i].from){var n=100*(1-this._headers[i].progress);n>=100&&(n=110),n<=-100&&(n=-110),"top"===this._headers[i].from?this._transformMode!==!1?(this._headers[i].element[0].style[this._transformMode]="translateY(-"+n+"%) translateZ(0)",this._headers[i].inner[0].style[this._transformMode]="translateY(+"+n+"%) translateZ(0)"):(this._headers[i].element[0].style.top="-"+n+"%",this._headers[i].inner[0].style.top="+"+n+"%"):this._transformMode!==!1?(this._headers[i].element[0].style[this._transformMode]="translateY(+"+n+"%) translateZ(0)",this._headers[i].inner[0].style[this._transformMode]="translateY(-"+n+"%) translateZ(0)"):(this._headers[i].element[0].style.top="+"+n+"%",this._headers[i].inner[0].style.top="-"+n+"%")}}},_recalculateSections:function(){this._documentHeight=t(document).height(),this._sections=[];for(var e=0;e<this._$sections.length;e++){var s=t(this._$sections[e]);this._sections.push({element:s,className:s.data(this.options.sectionSelector),start:s.offset().top,end:s.offset().top+s.outerHeight()})}},_updateHeaderHeight:function(){this._headerInfo.height=this._getContainerHeight(),this.element.css("height",this._headerInfo.height+"px")},_updateHeadersLoop:function(){var t=this;this._requestAnimationFrame(function(){t._updateHeadersLoop()}),this._recalculateHeaders(),this._updateHeaders()},_requestAnimationFrame:function(t){var e=e||function(){return window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||function(t){window.setTimeout(t,1e3/60)}}();e(t)}})}(jQuery);
```

```css
body{font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;}

/* base style */

a{text-decoration: none}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,i{color: #000; padding-bottom: 30px;}
p{line-height: 28px; font-weight: 300px; color: #666;}
.big-text{ font-size: 70px; font-weight: 900;}
.medium-text{font-size: 40px;}
.normal-text{font-size: 20px;}
.small-text{font-size: 14px}
.intro-text{ text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;}
.button{ background: #316bff; padding: 18px 28px; color: #fff; display: inline-block; border-radius: 4px;}
.subtitle{color: #000; text-decoration: underline;}

/* header */
.header{
  width: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.default{; color: #000;}
.white{ color: red;}

.menu{width: 100%; color: #fff; transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);}
.menu li{display: inline-block; }
.menu li a{;display: block; padding: 15px; color: #000; font-weight: 700;}

/* hero */
.hero{
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.6)),
  url('img/hero.jpg'), no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex; width: 100%; align-items: center;
}
.hero__content{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
}
.hero__content h1,
.hero__content p {
  color: #fff;
}

/* poster */
.poster{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}


/* helpers */
.mt-1{margin-top: 50px;}
.mt-2{margin-top: 100px;}
.mt-3{margin-top: 150px;}
.tw{color: #fff;}


*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!-- header -->
<nav class="header">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Statistiche</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Giocatori</a></li>
    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- hero -->
<div class="hero " data-midnight="default" >
  <div class="hero__content reveal">
    <p class="intro-text">Il sito guida di</p>
    <h1 class="big-text">Goodgame Empire</h1>
    <a href="" class="button">Scopri di più</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- poster -->
<section class="poster mt-3 " data-midnight="white">
  <div class="poster__content">
    <h3 class="big-text">Statistiche</h3>
    <p>Acquisici una conoscenza più approfondita della situazione in Goodgame Empire.<br>Questo sito ti offre gratuitamente in un unico posto tutti gli strumenti di cui hai bisogno per analizzare i rendimenti delle coalizioni, le varie classifiche, e le guerre svolte.
    </p>
    <a href="" class="button">Scopri di più</a>
  </div>
</section>







<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="midnight.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Start midnight
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Change this to the correct selector.
  $('.menu li a').midnight();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, running the snippet throws errors and doesn't reproduce what's described in the question, please add the required dependencies...

Comment: @TJ    

now it should go. I would like to do the same thing you see in the snippet in header, but with letters

Comment: The demo seems to work fine..?

Comment: @TJ

yes, it's okay when I put on

$ ('nav.header'). midnight ();

if I put it though

$ ('. menu li a'). midnight ();

the menu is all in the center.

I edited them snippet so you see...

Comment: @TJ

i have already tried every way but i can't solve

Comment: exactly.  

the problem is that in the header of the site I also have a logo and a button.
So if I put

$ ('nav.header'). midnight ();

the logo from the left goes above the menu, and the button from the right goes below the menu. I don't know why but everything tends to go to the center

@TJ

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can use CSS to do this:

```
.white ul li a {
  color: white;
}
```

```js
/*!
 * Midnight.js 1.1.1
 * jQuery plugin to switch between multiple fixed header designs on the fly, so it looks in line with the content below it.
 * http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Aerolab <info@aerolab.co>
 *
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/LICENSE.txt
 */
! function(t) {
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], t) : t(jQuery)
}(function(t) {
  var e = 0,
    s = Array.prototype.slice;
  t.cleanData = function(e) {
    return function(s) {
      var i, n, o;
      for (o = 0; null != (n = s[o]); o++) try {
        i = t._data(n, "events"), i && i.remove && t(n).triggerHandler("remove")
      } catch (r) {}
      e(s)
    }
  }(t.cleanData), t.widget = function(e, s, i) {
    var n, o, r, a, h = {},
      d = e.split(".")[0];
    return e = e.split(".")[1], n = d + "-" + e, i || (i = s, s = t.Widget), t.expr[":"][n.toLowerCase()] = function(e) {
      return !!t.data(e, n)
    }, t[d] = t[d] || {}, o = t[d][e], r = t[d][e] = function(t, e) {
      return this._createWidget ? void(arguments.length && this._createWidget(t, e)) : new r(t, e)
    }, t.extend(r, o, {
      version: i.version,
      _proto: t.extend({}, i),
      _childConstructors: []
    }), a = new s, a.options = t.widget.extend({}, a.options), t.each(i, function(e, i) {
      return t.isFunction(i) ? void(h[e] = function() {
        var t = function() {
            return s.prototype[e].apply(this, arguments)
          },
          n = function(t) {
            return s.prototype[e].apply(this, t)
          };
        return function() {
          var e, s = this._super,
            o = this._superApply;
          return this._super = t, this._superApply = n, e = i.apply(this, arguments), this._super = s, this._superApply = o, e
        }
      }()) : void(h[e] = i)
    }), r.prototype = t.widget.extend(a, {
      widgetEventPrefix: o ? a.widgetEventPrefix || e : e
    }, h, {
      constructor: r,
      namespace: d,
      widgetName: e,
      widgetFullName: n
    }), o ? (t.each(o._childConstructors, function(e, s) {
      var i = s.prototype;
      t.widget(i.namespace + "." + i.widgetName, r, s._proto)
    }), delete o._childConstructors) : s._childConstructors.push(r), t.widget.bridge(e, r), r
  }, t.widget.extend = function(e) {
    for (var i, n, o = s.call(arguments, 1), r = 0, a = o.length; a > r; r++)
      for (i in o[r]) n = o[r][i], o[r].hasOwnProperty(i) && void 0 !== n && (e[i] = t.isPlainObject(n) ? t.isPlainObject(e[i]) ? t.widget.extend({}, e[i], n) : t.widget.extend({}, n) : n);
    return e
  }, t.widget.bridge = function(e, i) {
    var n = i.prototype.widgetFullName || e;
    t.fn[e] = function(o) {
      var r = "string" == typeof o,
        a = s.call(arguments, 1),
        h = this;
      return o = !r && a.length ? t.widget.extend.apply(null, [o].concat(a)) : o, r ? this.each(function() {
        var s, i = t.data(this, n);
        return "instance" === o ? (h = i, !1) : i ? t.isFunction(i[o]) && "_" !== o.charAt(0) ? (s = i[o].apply(i, a), s !== i && void 0 !== s ? (h = s && s.jquery ? h.pushStack(s.get()) : s, !1) : void 0) : t.error("no such method '" + o + "' for " + e + " widget instance") : t.error("cannot call methods on " + e + " prior to initialization; attempted to call method '" + o + "'")
      }) : this.each(function() {
        var e = t.data(this, n);
        e ? (e.option(o || {}), e._init && e._init()) : t.data(this, n, new i(o, this))
      }), h
    }
  }, t.Widget = function() {}, t.Widget._childConstructors = [], t.Widget.prototype = {
    widgetName: "widget",
    widgetEventPrefix: "",
    defaultElement: "<div>",
    options: {
      disabled: !1,
      create: null
    },
    _createWidget: function(s, i) {
      i = t(i || this.defaultElement || this)[0], this.element = t(i), this.uuid = e++, this.eventNamespace = "." + this.widgetName + this.uuid, this.bindings = t(), this.hoverable = t(), this.focusable = t(), i !== this && (t.data(i, this.widgetFullName, this), this._on(!0, this.element, {
        remove: function(t) {
          t.target === i && this.destroy()
        }
      }), this.document = t(i.style ? i.ownerDocument : i.document || i), this.window = t(this.document[0].defaultView || this.document[0].parentWindow)), this.options = t.widget.extend({}, this.options, this._getCreateOptions(), s), this._create(), this._trigger("create", null, this._getCreateEventData()), this._init()
    },
    _getCreateOptions: t.noop,
    _getCreateEventData: t.noop,
    _create: t.noop,
    _init: t.noop,
    destroy: function() {
      this._destroy(), this.element.unbind(this.eventNamespace).removeData(this.widgetFullName).removeData(t.camelCase(this.widgetFullName)), this.widget().unbind(this.eventNamespace).removeAttr("aria-disabled").removeClass(this.widgetFullName + "-disabled ui-state-disabled"), this.bindings.unbind(this.eventNamespace), this.hoverable.removeClass("ui-state-hover"), this.focusable.removeClass("ui-state-focus")
    },
    _destroy: t.noop,
    widget: function() {
      return this.element
    },
    option: function(e, s) {
      var i, n, o, r = e;
      if (0 === arguments.length) return t.widget.extend({}, this.options);
      if ("string" == typeof e)
        if (r = {}, i = e.split("."), e = i.shift(), i.length) {
          for (n = r[e] = t.widget.extend({}, this.options[e]), o = 0; i.length - 1 > o; o++) n[i[o]] = n[i[o]] || {}, n = n[i[o]];
          if (e = i.pop(), 1 === arguments.length) return void 0 === n[e] ? null : n[e];
          n[e] = s
        } else {
          if (1 === arguments.length) return void 0 === this.options[e] ? null : this.options[e];
          r[e] = s
        }
      return this._setOptions(r), this
    },
    _setOptions: function(t) {
      var e;
      for (e in t) this._setOption(e, t[e]);
      return this
    },
    _setOption: function(t, e) {
      return this.options[t] = e, "disabled" === t && (this.widget().toggleClass(this.widgetFullName + "-disabled", !!e), e && (this.hoverable.removeClass("ui-state-hover"), this.focusable.removeClass("ui-state-focus"))), this
    },
    enable: function() {
      return this._setOptions({
        disabled: !1
      })
    },
    disable: function() {
      return this._setOptions({
        disabled: !0
      })
    },
    _on: function(e, s, i) {
      var n, o = this;
      "boolean" != typeof e && (i = s, s = e, e = !1), i ? (s = n = t(s), this.bindings = this.bindings.add(s)) : (i = s, s = this.element, n = this.widget()), t.each(i, function(i, r) {
        function a() {
          return e || o.options.disabled !== !0 && !t(this).hasClass("ui-state-disabled") ? ("string" == typeof r ? o[r] : r).apply(o, arguments) : void 0
        }
        "string" != typeof r && (a.guid = r.guid = r.guid || a.guid || t.guid++);
        var h = i.match(/^([\w:-]*)\s*(.*)$/),
          d = h[1] + o.eventNamespace,
          l = h[2];
        l ? n.delegate(l, d, a) : s.bind(d, a)
      })
    },
    _off: function(e, s) {
      s = (s || "").split(" ").join(this.eventNamespace + " ") + this.eventNamespace, e.unbind(s).undelegate(s), this.bindings = t(this.bindings.not(e).get()), this.focusable = t(this.focusable.not(e).get()), this.hoverable = t(this.hoverable.not(e).get())
    },
    _delay: function(t, e) {
      function s() {
        return ("string" == typeof t ? i[t] : t).apply(i, arguments)
      }
      var i = this;
      return setTimeout(s, e || 0)
    },
    _hoverable: function(e) {
      this.hoverable = this.hoverable.add(e), this._on(e, {
        mouseenter: function(e) {
          t(e.currentTarget).addClass("ui-state-hover")
        },
        mouseleave: function(e) {
          t(e.currentTarget).removeClass("ui-state-hover")
        }
      })
    },
    _focusable: function(e) {
      this.focusable = this.focusable.add(e), this._on(e, {
        focusin: function(e) {
          t(e.currentTarget).addClass("ui-state-focus")
        },
        focusout: function(e) {
          t(e.currentTarget).removeClass("ui-state-focus")
        }
      })
    },
    _trigger: function(e, s, i) {
      var n, o, r = this.options[e];
      if (i = i || {}, s = t.Event(s), s.type = (e === this.widgetEventPrefix ? e : this.widgetEventPrefix + e).toLowerCase(), s.target = this.element[0], o = s.originalEvent)
        for (n in o) n in s || (s[n] = o[n]);
      return this.element.trigger(s, i), !(t.isFunction(r) && r.apply(this.element[0], [s].concat(i)) === !1 || s.isDefaultPrevented())
    }
  }, t.each({
    show: "fadeIn",
    hide: "fadeOut"
  }, function(e, s) {
    t.Widget.prototype["_" + e] = function(i, n, o) {
      "string" == typeof n && (n = {
        effect: n
      });
      var r, a = n ? n === !0 || "number" == typeof n ? s : n.effect || s : e;
      n = n || {}, "number" == typeof n && (n = {
        duration: n
      }), r = !t.isEmptyObject(n), n.complete = o, n.delay && i.delay(n.delay), r && t.effects && t.effects.effect[a] ? i[e](n) : a !== e && i[a] ? i[a](n.duration, n.easing, o) : i.queue(function(s) {
        t(this)[e](), o && o.call(i[0]), s()
      })
    }
  }), t.widget
}),
function(t) {
  "use strict";
  t.widget("aerolab.midnight", {
    options: {
      headerClass: "midnightHeader",
      innerClass: "midnightInner",
      defaultClass: "default",
      classPrefix: "",
      sectionSelector: "midnight"
    },
    _headers: {},
    _headerInfo: {
      top: 0,
      height: 0
    },
    _$sections: [],
    _sections: [],
    _scrollTop: 0,
    _documentHeight: 0,
    _transformMode: !1,
    refresh: function() {
      this._headerInfo = {
        top: 0,
        height: this.element.outerHeight()
      }, this._$sections = t("[data-" + this.options.sectionSelector + "]:not(:hidden)"), this._sections = [], this._setupHeaders(), this.recalculate()
    },
    _create: function() {
      var e = this;
      this._scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop, this._documentHeight = t(document).height(), this._headers = {}, this._transformMode = this._getSupportedTransform(), this.refresh(), setInterval(function() {
        e._recalculateSections()
      }, 1e3), e.recalculate(), t(window).resize(function() {
        e.recalculate()
      }), this._updateHeadersLoop()
    },
    recalculate: function() {
      this._recalculateSections(), this._updateHeaderHeight(), this._recalculateHeaders(), this._updateHeaders()
    },
    _getSupportedTransform: function() {
      for (var t = ["transform", "WebkitTransform", "MozTransform", "OTransform", "msTransform"], e = 0; e < t.length; e++)
        if (void 0 !== document.createElement("div").style[t[e]]) return t[e];
      return !1
    },
    _getContainerHeight: function() {
      var e = this.element.find("> ." + this.options.headerClass),
        s = 0,
        i = 0,
        n = this;
      return e.length ? e.each(function() {
        var e = t(this),
          o = e.find("> ." + n.options.innerClass);
        o.length ? (o.css("bottom", "auto").css("overflow", "auto"), i = o.outerHeight(), o.css("bottom", "0")) : (e.css("bottom", "auto"), i = e.outerHeight(), e.css("bottom", "0")), s = i > s ? i : s
      }) : s = i = this.element.outerHeight(), s
    },
    _setupHeaders: function() {
      var e = this;
      this._headers[this.options.defaultClass] = {};
      for (var s = 0; s < this._$sections.length; s++) {
        var i = t(this._$sections[s]),
          n = i.data(this.options.sectionSelector);
        "string" == typeof n && (n = n.trim(), "" !== n && (e._headers[n] = {}))
      }({
        top: this.element.css("padding-top"),
        right: this.element.css("padding-right"),
        bottom: this.element.css("padding-bottom"),
        left: this.element.css("padding-left")
      });
      this.element.css({
        position: "fixed",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        overflow: "hidden"
      }), this._updateHeaderHeight();
      var o = this.element.find("> ." + this.options.headerClass);
      o.length ? o.filter("." + this.options.defaultClass).length || o.filter("." + this.options.headerClass + ":first").clone(!0, !0).attr("class", this.options.headerClass + " " + this.options.defaultClass) : this.element.wrapInner('<div class="' + this.options.headerClass + " " + this.options.defaultClass + '"></div>');
      var o = this.element.find("> ." + this.options.headerClass),
        r = o.filter("." + this.options.defaultClass).clone(!0, !0);
      for (var n in this._headers)
        if (this._headers.hasOwnProperty(n) && "undefined" == typeof this._headers[n].element) {
          var a = o.filter("." + n);
          a.length ? this._headers[n].element = a : this._headers[n].element = r.clone(!0, !0).removeClass(this.options.defaultClass).addClass(n).appendTo(this.element);
          var h = {
            position: "absolute",
            overflow: "hidden",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0
          };
          this._headers[n].element.css(h), this._transformMode !== !1 && this._headers[n].element.css(this._transformMode, "translateZ(0)"), this._headers[n].element.find("> ." + this.options.innerClass).length || this._headers[n].element.wrapInner('<div class="' + this.options.innerClass + '"></div>'), this._headers[n].inner = this._headers[n].element.find("> ." + this.options.innerClass), this._headers[n].inner.css(h), this._transformMode !== !1 && this._headers[n].inner.css(this._transformMode, "translateZ(0)"), this._headers[n].from = "", this._headers[n].progress = 0
        }
      o.each(function() {
        var s = t(this),
          i = !1;
        for (var n in e._headers) e._headers.hasOwnProperty(n) && s.hasClass(n) && (i = !0);
        s.find("> ." + e.options.innerClass).length || s.wrapInner('<div class="' + e.options.innerClass + '"></div>'), i ? s.show() : s.hide()
      })
    },
    _recalculateHeaders: function() {
      this._scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop, this._scrollTop = Math.max(this._scrollTop, 0), this._scrollTop = Math.min(this._scrollTop, this._documentHeight);
      var t = this._headerInfo.height,
        e = this._scrollTop + this._headerInfo.top,
        s = e + t;
      if ("function" == typeof window.getComputedStyle) {
        var i = window.getComputedStyle(this.element[0], null),
          n = 0,
          o = 0;
        if (this._transformMode !== !1 && "string" == typeof i.transform) {
          var r = i.transform.match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)/g);
          null !== r && r.length >= 6 && !isNaN(parseFloat(r[5])) && (o = parseFloat(r[5]))
        }
        i.top.indexOf("px") >= 0 && !isNaN(parseFloat(i.top)) && (n = parseFloat(i.top)), e += n + o, s += n + o
      }
      for (var a in this._headers) this._headers.hasOwnProperty(a) && (this._headers[a].from = "", this._headers[a].progress = 0);
      for (var h = 0; h < this._sections.length; h++) s >= this._sections[h].start && e <= this._sections[h].end && (this._headers[this._sections[h].className].visible = !0, e >= this._sections[h].start && s <= this._sections[h].end ? (this._headers[this._sections[h].className].from = "top", this._headers[this._sections[h].className].progress += 1) : s > this._sections[h].end && e < this._sections[h].end ? (this._headers[this._sections[h].className].from = "top", this._headers[this._sections[h].className].progress = 1 - (s - this._sections[h].end) / t) : s > this._sections[h].start && e < this._sections[h].start && ("top" === this._headers[this._sections[h].className].from ? this._headers[this._sections[h].className].progress += (s - this._sections[h].start) / t : (this._headers[this._sections[h].className].from = "bottom", this._headers[this._sections[h].className].progress = (s - this._sections[h].start) / t)))
    },
    _updateHeaders: function() {
      if ("undefined" != typeof this._headers[this.options.defaultClass]) {
        var t = 0,
          e = "";
        for (var s in this._headers) this._headers.hasOwnProperty(s) && "" !== !this._headers[s].from && (t += this._headers[s].progress, e = s);
        t < 1 && ("" === this._headers[this.options.defaultClass].from ? (this._headers[this.options.defaultClass].from = "top" === this._headers[e].from ? "bottom" : "top", this._headers[this.options.defaultClass].progress = 1 - t) : this._headers[this.options.defaultClass].progress += 1 - t);
        for (var i in this._headers)
          if (this._headers.hasOwnProperty(i) && "" !== !this._headers[i].from) {
            var n = 100 * (1 - this._headers[i].progress);
            n >= 100 && (n = 110), n <= -100 && (n = -110), "top" === this._headers[i].from ? this._transformMode !== !1 ? (this._headers[i].element[0].style[this._transformMode] = "translateY(-" + n + "%) translateZ(0)", this._headers[i].inner[0].style[this._transformMode] = "translateY(+" + n + "%) translateZ(0)") : (this._headers[i].element[0].style.top = "-" + n + "%", this._headers[i].inner[0].style.top = "+" + n + "%") : this._transformMode !== !1 ? (this._headers[i].element[0].style[this._transformMode] = "translateY(+" + n + "%) translateZ(0)", this._headers[i].inner[0].style[this._transformMode] = "translateY(-" + n + "%) translateZ(0)") : (this._headers[i].element[0].style.top = "+" + n + "%", this._headers[i].inner[0].style.top = "-" + n + "%")
          }
      }
    },
    _recalculateSections: function() {
      this._documentHeight = t(document).height(), this._sections = [];
      for (var e = 0; e < this._$sections.length; e++) {
        var s = t(this._$sections[e]);
        this._sections.push({
          element: s,
          className: s.data(this.options.sectionSelector),
          start: s.offset().top,
          end: s.offset().top + s.outerHeight()
        })
      }
    },
    _updateHeaderHeight: function() {
      this._headerInfo.height = this._getContainerHeight(), this.element.css("height", this._headerInfo.height + "px")
    },
    _updateHeadersLoop: function() {
      var t = this;
      this._requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        t._updateHeadersLoop()
      }), this._recalculateHeaders(), this._updateHeaders()
    },
    _requestAnimationFrame: function(t) {
      var e = e || function() {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function(t) {
          window.setTimeout(t, 1e3 / 60)
        }
      }();
      e(t)
    }
  })
}(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* base style */

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
i {
  color: #000;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

p {
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 300px;
  color: #666;
}

.big-text {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.medium-text {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.normal-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.small-text {
  font-size: 14px
}

.intro-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button {
  background: #316bff;
  padding: 18px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.subtitle {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* header */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.default {
  background: #316bff;
  color: #000;
}

.white {
  background: red;
  color: red;
}

.white ul li a{
  color: white;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li a {
  ;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
}


/* hero */

.hero {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)), url('img/hero.jpg'), no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.hero__content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
}

.hero__content h1,
.hero__content p {
  color: #fff;
}


/* poster */

.poster {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}


/* helpers */

.mt-1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.mt-2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.mt-3 {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.tw {
  color: #fff;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!-- header -->
<nav class="header">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Statistiche</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Giocatori</a></li>
    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- hero -->
<div class="hero " data-midnight="default">
  <div class="hero__content reveal">
    <p class="intro-text">Il sito guida di</p>
    <h1 class="big-text">Goodgame Empire</h1>
    <a href="" class="button">Scopri di più</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- poster -->
<section class="poster mt-3 " data-midnight="white">
  <div class="poster__content">
    <h3 class="big-text">Statistiche</h3>
    <p>Acquisici una conoscenza più approfondita della situazione in Goodgame Empire.<br>Questo sito ti offre gratuitamente in un unico posto tutti gli strumenti di cui hai bisogno per analizzare i rendimenti delle coalizioni, le varie classifiche, e le
      guerre svolte.
    </p>
    <a href="" class="button">Scopri di più</a>
  </div>
</section>







<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="midnight.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // Start midnight
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Change this to the correct selector.
    $('nav.header').midnight();
  });
</script>
```